# the method was called on null in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, error-handling, flutter-layout

greeting to all,
I am stuck in a situation where I am getting data from the back end but initially it the error is displayed on the phone before the app starts.
below is the image of the error.

[image]

after showing this the app starts. how do I handle this error? I tried the spin kit but it is not working.
I want to show this on the console.
below is the code -:

```
import 'package:education/LogIn_SignUp/Log_In.dart';
import 'package:education/Screens/Profile_Screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'About_Scree.dart';
import 'Change_Password.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';



class homeView extends StatefulWidget{

  var user_id;
  var user_name;
  var mobile_number;
  var user_address;
  var user_Email;
  var coaching_id;
  var coaching_name;
  var coaching_address;
  var primary_no;
  var altnumber;
  var coaching_email;



  homeView({
    this.user_id,this.user_name,this.mobile_number,this.user_address,this.coaching_id,this.coaching_name,
    this.coaching_address,this.primary_no,this.altnumber,this.coaching_email,this.user_Email
});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => homeViewState();
}



class homeViewState extends State<homeView> {


  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  var showItemList = List<String>();
  int count = 10;




  var userid, username, mobilenumber, useraddress, userEmail, coachingid, coachingname, coachingaddress;
  var primaryno, alt_number, coachingemail;

  void setdata(){
    setState(() {
      userid = widget.user_id;
      username = widget.user_name;
      mobilenumber = widget.mobile_number;
      useraddress = widget.user_address;
      userEmail = widget.user_Email;
      coachingid = widget.coaching_id;
      coachingname = widget.coaching_name;
      coachingaddress = widget.coaching_address;
    });
  }



  @override
  void initState(){
    // showItemList.addAll(initList);
    // getData();
    setdata();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    editingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ///                                           Main Build Function for the class.
  /// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(90.0),
          child: AppBar(
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Text(
                '$coachingname',//'${widget.coaching_name}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  letterSpacing: 4.5,
                  fontFamily: 'Sarif',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    child: new IconButton(
                        icon: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                          child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                        ),
                        onPressed:(){
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                          ));
                        }
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => LoginPage()
                      ));
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[

                Container(
                  height: 180,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                      Colors.purple.shade300,
                      Colors.deepPurpleAccent.shade200,
                    ]),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0, bottom: 10),
                        child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(55),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.perm_identity_outlined, color: Colors.white,size: 30),
                            )
                        ),
                      ),

                      Text(
                        '$username',//'${widget.user_name}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          letterSpacing: 2.5,
                        ),
                      ),


                    ],
                  ),
                ),


                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Profile',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                  ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person_pin, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ProfilePage(
                        user_id: userid, user_name:username, mobile_number:mobilenumber, user_address:useraddress,
                        user_Email: userEmail,
                      )
                    ));
                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Change Password',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.security, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ChangePassword()
                    ));
                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('About',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                  ),
                ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.info_outline, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AboutScreen(
                        coaching_id:coachingid, coaching_name:coachingname, coaching_address:coachingaddress,
                        primary_no:primaryno, altnumber:alt_number, coaching_email:coachingemail
                      )//coaching details
                    ));
                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Rate',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),


                Divider(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  thickness: 1,
                ),


                SizedBox(height: 10,),

                Text(
                  'Contact Us',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 10,),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Share',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Privacy Policy',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.privacy_tip, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'LogOut',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.logout, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => LoginPage()
                    ));

                  },
                ),



              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

can I have some idea to handle this thing?

this is the exception shown on console -:

```
 ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building LoginPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: LoginPageState#6cbef(ticker active)):
LoginPageState is a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin but multiple tickers were created.

A SingleTickerProviderStateMixin can only be used as a TickerProvider once.

If a State is used for multiple AnimationController objects, or if it is passed to other objects and those objects might use it more than one time in total, then instead of mixing in a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, use a regular TickerProviderStateMixin.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  LoginPage file:///C:/Users/PALAK/AndroidStudioProjects/education/lib/main.dart:35:7
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      SingleTickerProviderStateMixin.createTicker.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:121:7)
#1      SingleTickerProviderStateMixin.createTicker (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:130:6)
#2      new AnimationController (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:248:21)
#3      LoginPageState.build (package:education/LogIn_SignUp/Log_In.dart:250:21)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
```

below is the code of login page -:

```
import 'package:education/Screens/Home_View.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'SignUp.dart';


class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return LoginPageState();
  }
}


class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  bool isLoading = false;


  GlobalKey<FormState> formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final FocusNode focusNode = new FocusNode();


  var usermail, password, C_id;

  TextEditingController userEmail1 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController userPassword1= new TextEditingController();



  var userid, username, mobilenumber, useraddress, coachingid, coachingname, coachingaddress, primaryno, altno, coachingemail;

  var Coaching_name, Coaching_id;
  var data;

  Future<http.Request> getData() async
  {
    var client = new http.Client();
    final response = await client.get('http://192.168.0.104:5000/coaching_detail');
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if(responseJson == null) {
        setState(() {
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
              child: isLoading ? SpinKitSquareCircle(
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 50.0,
                controller: AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: const Duration(seconds: 3)),
              ): Container(height: 200,)
              //isLoading == true ? Text('Loading ...') : Text('Loading ...'),
          );
        });
      }
      else {
        setState(() {
          dynamic coaching_id = responseJson['coachid'];
          dynamic coaching_name = responseJson['coachname'];

          Coaching_name = coaching_name;
          Coaching_id = coaching_id;
          data = responseJson;
        });
      }


    print(responseJson);
    client.close();
  }


  int i = 2;



  Future signInWithUserNameAndPassword(String email, String Password, String coachid) async {

    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        'http://192.168.0.104:5000/user_login',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'useremail': email,
          'userpassword': Password,
          'coachid' : coachid,
        }),
      );
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

      print(responseJson);



      if (responseJson['coach_id'] != null) {
        print('success');
        print(responseJson);

            setState(() {
              dynamic user_id = responseJson['userid'];
              dynamic user_name = responseJson['user_name'];
              dynamic mobile_number = responseJson['mobile_number'];
              dynamic user_address = responseJson['user_address'];
              dynamic coaching_id = responseJson['coach_id'];
              dynamic coach_name = responseJson['coach_name'];
              dynamic coach_address = responseJson['coach_address'];
              dynamic primary_no = responseJson['primary_no'];
              dynamic alt_number = responseJson['alt_number'];
              dynamic coaching_email = responseJson['coaching_email'];


              userid = user_id;
              username = user_name;
              mobilenumber = mobile_number;
              useraddress = user_address;
              coachingid = coaching_id;
              coachingname = coach_name;
              coachingaddress = coach_address;
              primaryno = primary_no;
              altno = alt_number;
              coachingemail = coaching_email;

            });


        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => homeView(
              user_id: userid, user_name:username, mobile_number:mobilenumber, user_address:useraddress,
              coaching_id:coachingid, coaching_name:coachingname, coaching_address:coachingaddress,
              primary_no:primaryno, altnumber:altno, coaching_email:coachingemail, user_Email:usermail,

          ),
        ));
      }
      else{
        print('fail');
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Error"),
                content: Text("Incorrect Credentials"),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Ok"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context)=> LoginPage()
                      ));
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  signIn(){
    if(formkey.currentState.validate()){
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      usermail = userEmail1.text;
      password = userPassword1.text;
      C_id = Coaching_id[i].toString();

      signInWithUserNameAndPassword(usermail, password, C_id);
     
    }
  }



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }


  @override
  void dispose(){
    userEmail1.dispose();
    userPassword1.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .height;
    double width = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading ? SpinKitSquareCircle(
        color: Colors.red,
        size: 50.0,
        controller: AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: const Duration(seconds: 3)),
      )
          : Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: formkey,
            // autovalidate: true,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Colors.lightBlueAccent, Colors.blueAccent],
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, bottom: 20.0),
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${Coaching_name[i]}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 45.0,
                          letterSpacing: 4.5,
                          fontFamily: 'Sarif',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 130.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: userEmail1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          prefixIcon: Container(
                              padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                 ),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                              )),
                          hintText: "enter your email",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                        ),
                        validator: MultiValidator(
                            [
                              RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required'),
                              // EmailValidator(errorText: 'not a valid Email'),
                            ]
                        ),
                        onSaved: (user) => usermail(user),
                      ),


                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: userPassword1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          prefixIcon: Container(
                              padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                              )),

                          hintText: "enter your password",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                        ),
                        obscureText: true,
                        validator: MultiValidator(
                            [
                              MinLengthValidator(4,
                                  errorText: 'should be atleast 6 characters'),
                              MaxLengthValidator(10,
                                  errorText: 'should not be more than 10 characters'),
                              RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required'),
                            ]
                        ),
                      ),


                      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          textColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Text("Login".toUpperCase()),
                          onPressed: () {
                            NavigationMode.directional;
                            signIn();
                          },
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),



                      SizedBox(height: 25,),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(height: 20,),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Don\'t have an account?",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                FlatButton(
                                  child: Text("Sign in",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  textColor: Colors.indigo,
                                  onPressed: (){

                                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => signUp()
                                    ));
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error code from the debug console?

Comment: can you give the console stacktrace. Also pinpoint at the error line that console is pointing you.

Comment: actually, there isn't any error in the code this just comes when this page is loaded.

Comment: Can you share the code of your LoginPage?

Comment: yes I shared the code ablove

Comment: Nearly always, "(something) called on null" means you didn't wait for some future to complete, so you're still in limbo.

Comment: based on your debug console you can either use TickerProviderStateMixin instead of SingleTickerProviderStateMixin or use only one AnimationController in your LoginPage

Comment: i tried TickerProviderStateMixin but no result

Answer (score 0):

This error is in your login page code where you are showing `'${Coaching_name[i]}'` but the variable Coaching_name is null before the data is fetched and you are trying to call the second index of a null variable. One of the simple way is change the code from

`Text('${Coaching_name[i]})'`

to

`Text(Coaching_name == null ? "" : Coaching_name[i])`

**EDIT 1**

Yes, the solution provide above is just a **simple** way for error handling.
I'm just letting you to know which part of your code went wrong. The widget is rendered before data is fetched. So you need to put a loading screen while fetching data.
there are few ways that you may refer.

1. Use FutureBuilder. You may click [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for example.
2. Use [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) plugin
3. Use any state management eg. Provider

Personally preferred to use state management to keep the code clean. But if you're still new in flutter you may go for FutureBuilder and apply on every page that you are fetching data from back end.

Comment: This is one of the simple way to do error handling. You may also look on [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) to do a loading page when waiting data from server

Comment: but error like this can be screen on almost every page where I am getting data from back end